# Swift - Switch multiple (x)html files in the same webview

Tags: html, swift, uiwebview, epub, reader

I have one webview in my view controller that I want to use as a reader. How can I switch between multiple (x)html files in this webview? I retrieve them one by one with the following code:

```
           apiClient.getData(forFile: file) { (data, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    //show error
                    return
                }

                if let data = data {
                    self.data = data

                    self.webView.load(data, mimeType: mimeType, textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: URL(string: "")!)
                }
            }
```

Right now When a user scrolls (horizontal) through the pages of an epub and transitions from one file to another, there is a short loading time (because it is retrieving the next xhtml from the server).

Right now, it is a jarring experience, preventing the user from scrolling forward. When the next file is loaded, the page jumps to the new one.

Comment: If you retrieve all the pages at once and keep them in memory, the transition will be smoother when loading a new page.

Comment: @Cristian That's the issue, I wan't to retrieve the pages page by page, just like I stream them. I don't want any pages in memory.